# Making a child process with redirected standard input/output to a pipe

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, stdio

I am trying to create a child process with redirected stdin/stdout.
I am creating a pipe to redirect  the stdin and write the stdout to a file.

Here is what I have tried

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    STARTUPINFOA sInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sAttr;
    ZeroMemory(&sInfo, sizeof(sInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(pInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&sAttr, sizeof(sAttr));
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
    sAttr.bInheritHandle = true;
    HANDLE fileTest = CreateFileA("hello.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sAttr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE stdinPipe = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\DokiDokiIn", PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024, 1024, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, &sAttr);
    sInfo.hStdInput = stdinPipe;
    sInfo.hStdOutput = fileTest;
    sInfo.hStdError = fileTest;
    sInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    char cmdLine[] = "cmd.exe";
    bool success = CreateProcessA("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", NULL, &sAttr, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
    if (!success) {
        std::cout << "CreateProcessA() failed with error " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << GetLastError() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, whenever I specify `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` as dwFlags the opened process instantly closes (or doesn't open at all, not sure). It works when I don't specify flags but I/O aren't redirected.
Also, as expected writing to it using my pipe client doesn't work, it can't get a handle to that pipe.
CreateFile is always true and the handle values seem valid, GetLastError() returns 0 but the program just exits and there is no popup with a child process, and even if it was running in the background I cannot write to it.

Comment: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

Comment: I have attempted something similar but I am unsure as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your represented code, two issues are found:

1. Set `bInheritHandles` parameter of `CreateProcessA` to `TRUE` instead of `NULL` to make each inheritable handle in the calling process is inherited by the new process (here is `cmd.exe`).
2. `cmd.exe` shows version information after launched and exits. You can set command line for `cmd.exe` to make it running continuously if you want to prevent it from exiting.

A tip:

Call [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror#remarks) immediately after the function fails otherwise the error code may be set to `zero` by other functions.

The following is an example work for me. You can have a try.

```
int main()
{
    STARTUPINFOA sInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pInfo;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sAttr;
    ZeroMemory(&sInfo, sizeof(sInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&pInfo, sizeof(pInfo));
    ZeroMemory(&sAttr, sizeof(sAttr));
    sInfo.cb = sizeof(sInfo);
    sAttr.bInheritHandle = true;
    HANDLE fileTest = CreateFileA("hello.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sAttr, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE stdinPipe = CreateNamedPipeA("\\\\.\\pipe\\DokiDokiIn", PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT, 1, 1024, 1024, NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT, &sAttr);
    sInfo.hStdInput = stdinPipe;
    sInfo.hStdOutput = fileTest;
    sInfo.hStdError = fileTest;
    sInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    char input[] = "ping www.google.com -t";
    char cmd[] = "cmd.exe";
    // initialize cmd
    char cmdline[MAX_PATH];
    sprintf_s(cmdline, sizeof(cmdline), "%s /c %s", cmd, input);
    bool success = CreateProcessA("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", cmdline, &sAttr, NULL, TRUE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &sInfo, &pInfo);
    if (!success) {
        DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
        std::cout << "CreateProcessA() failed with error " << errCode << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```